# how to get the date set in the DatePickerDialog in android?

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

Solution not found it yet, I have spent a few hours to this challenge.
How can I get a date to see how when you press the "today" button?

Want to get a date that is displayed when you press the button "today".
And, we believe the process of trying to add information to the screen display of the specified date.

```
    DatePickerDialog dpdialog = new DatePickerDialog(me, new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int pickyear, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {

        }
    }, year, month-1, day);
    // Dialog(Positive Button)
    dpdialog.setButton(
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
            "set", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Positive Button
                    // How to get the date set
                    String day = dpdialog.getDayOfMonth();
                    String month = dpdialog.getMonth() + 1;
                    String year = dpdialog.getYear();
                }
            }    
            );

    // Dialog (Negative Button)
    dpdialog.setButton(
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, 
            "cancel", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Negative Button
                }
            }
            );

    // Dialog(Neutral Button)
    dpdialog.setButton(
            DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, 
            "today", 
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Neutral Button
                }
            }
            );

    dpdialog.show();
```

Comment: no one is going to bother answering your question if you don't bother to format your code.

Comment: I'm sorry.
I should have more questions and tidy.
Back once again to write my own, I tried to improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

Variables defined in outer class will be visible from inner class/inline method, so you can do it like this:

```
private String day;
private String month;
private String year;

DatePickerDialog dpdialog = new DatePickerDialog(me, new OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int pickyear, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // you have the picked year/month/day here.
        // For example:
        day = String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
        month = String.valueOf(monthOfYear);
        year = String.valueOf(pickyear);
    }

}, year, month-1, day);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer
I want to get a date that is displayed when the "set" button is pressed but I will.
I do not know is how to call when the "set" button "onDateSet" is pressed.
I'm sorry rudimentary questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //decleration
 final static int DATE_DIALOG_ID=1;
EditText dateedt;
String date_selected="";
int currentDay,currentYear,currentMonth,

//onCreate
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
        currentDay=calendar.get(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        currentYear=calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);
        currentMonth=calendar.get(calendar.MONTH)+1;

dateedt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dateedt);

dateedt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });
//methods
@Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            switch(id)
            {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                return new DatePickerDialog( this,mDateSetListener,currentYear,currentMonth-1,currentDay);
}
            return null;
        }

DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener=new OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(monthOfYear < 10 && !String.valueOf(monthOfYear).contains("0"))
                {
                    if(dayOfMonth < 10 && !String.valueOf(dayOfMonth).contains("0"))
                    {
                        date_selected = "0"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" -0"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" -"+String.valueOf(year);
                        //selectedDateForDb = String.valueOf(year)+"-"+"0"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"-0"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        date_selected = "0"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" -"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" -"+String.valueOf(year);
                        //selectedDateForDb = String.valueOf(year)+"-0"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                    }
                }
                else if(dayOfMonth < 10 && !String.valueOf(dayOfMonth).contains("0"))
                {
                    date_selected = String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" -0"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" -"+String.valueOf(year);
                    //selectedDateForDb = String.valueOf(year)+"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"-0"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
                }
                else
                {
                    date_selected = String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+" -"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)+" -"+String.valueOf(year);
                    //selectedDateForDb = String.valueOf(year)+"-"+String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)+"-"+String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);

                }
                dateedt.setText(date_selected);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer
My question was how wrong.
I want to get the date you are viewing in the "dialog" instead of "display".
Did you feel to get this information, and how difficult.