# How to access DIalog's positive and negative buttons in Android

Tags: android

I want to access the positive and negative buttons of Dialog in Android. Why because I want to restrict multiple time visibility of my dialog. That is why I need to access those buttons. But I don't know how to access. I've researched, but the results are for only alertdialog, not for dialog.

```
Dialog mDialog = new DatePickerDialog(IncomeActivity.this,
                 mDatesetListener, calender.get(Calendar.YEAR),
             calender.get(Calendar.MONTH), calender
             .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
mDialog.show();
```

I have tried the following code. But it does not help me.

```
mDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                                isDateClicked = false;
        }
});
```

`isDateClicked` is a `boolean` value. Before open the mDIalog I said it to as `true`. Now I want to set it as false while dismiss the dialog. 
How to access this mDialog's positive and negative buttons.

Comment: may be [`Dialog.setOnDismissListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)) is what you are looking for?

Comment: i think this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9677721/how-to-get-the-date-set-in-the-datepickerdialog-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  vmironov said i found the answer. Thank you so much for  vmironov. the answer is

```
mDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
            isDateClicked = no;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can use Alert Dialog so there you can manage the Positive and negative buttons try the below code :

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddSchedule.this);
 builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
 builder.setTitle("Alert dialog title");
 builder.setMessage("Dialog message");
 builder.setPositiveButton("Button1", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //DO TASK
  }
  });
 builder.setNegativeButton("Button2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    //DO TASK
 }
});

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Comment: I need for dialog only firend not for alertdialog.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mDialog.isShowing() to know if dialog is already up or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can go this way for the **ok** and **cancel** button in dialgbox.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("title");
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.launcher);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    Display_questions.this.finish(); // using this current activity is closed
                         // Do task here

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();   // using this dialog box is closed.
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show();
```

Good Luck.